# Android's Queue poll() call throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: android, exception, queue, nosuchelementexception

> I have a queue implementation. To perform a de-queue I use the poll() API to
>   remove the head, but it throws the NoSuchElementException which it
>   shouldn't. Can anyone explain me why this happens? My queue has more than
>   enough data to be de-queued.

```
protected boolean enQueue(ByteBuffer data){
    if (queue.offer(data)){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }   
}

protected ByteBuffer deQueue(){
    ByteBuffer data = null;
    try{
        if(getQueueCount() > 0)
        {
            data = queue.poll();
            if(data != null){
                return data;
            }else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
java.util.Queue<ByteBuffer> queue;

public Queue(){
    queue = new LinkedList<ByteBuffer>();
}
protected int getQueueCount(){
    return queue.size();
}
```

> **StackTrace:**
>
> 03-04 14:58:50.205: W/System.err(7937): java.util.NoSuchElementException
>   03-04 14:58:50.205: W/System.err(7937):     at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirstImpl(LinkedList.java:689)
>   03-04 14:58:50.205: W/System.err(7937):     at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:676)
>   03-04 14:58:50.205: W/System.err(7937):     at java.util.LinkedList.poll(LinkedList.java:895)
>   03-04 14:58:50.205: W/System.err(7937):     at com.android.testapp.Queue.deQueue(Queue.java:37)
>   03-04 14:58:50.205: W/System.err(7937):     at com.android.testapp.DisplayData.run(LogViewActivity.java:1164)

**EDIT 2:**

**ENQUEUE**

```
Queue.getInstance().enQueue(tempByteBufRead);
```

> This I use to enqueue the data received through Bluetooth in bluetooth.class. tempByteBufRead is a Bytebuffer. And this is done in a separate thread.

**DEQUEUE**

```
while( Queue.getInstance().getQueueCount() <= 0);


        try {
            if(LLTestAppActivity.DEBUG){
                Log.d("DisplayData", "Crossed queue count...");
            }
            ByteBuffer tempByteBuf = Queue.getInstance().deQueue(); 
            if(null == tempByteBuf){
                Log.d("DisplayData", "No data in queue...");
            }
            else{
                   //TODO:
                 }
            }catch(){}
```

> This is how I dequeue. This is in different class file. And this is another thread used to display data onto a text view.

Comment: 1) Please post actual exception stacktrace as `poll()` shouldn't throw that exception 2) What's `getQueueCount()`?

Comment: Seems like you've implemented your own `Queue` and the problem is there. So, post your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queue is empty (or rather, missing its first element). The poll method in LinkedList is implemented as such:

```
public E poll() {
    if (size==0)
        return null;
    return removeFirst();
}
```

and removeFirst is a method that does throw NoSuchElementException.

You should try and figure out what causes the first element to go missing, since apparently your queue reports a non-zero number of elements. How do you push objects onto the queue?

EDIT:
Suggested changes to your code after seeing your edits:

```
// use a thread-safe queue implementation:
java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<ByteBuffer> queue;

// make the constructor private, since it's a singleton you don't want anyone else to be able to instantiate
private Queue() {
    queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer>();
}

// enQueue and deQueue without a bunch of redundant code:
protected boolean enQueue(ByteBuffer data) {
    return queue.offer(data);
}

protected ByteBuffer deQueue() {
    return queue.take();
}

// enqueue data like this:
Queue.getInstance().enQueue(tempByteBufRead);

// and dequeue it:
try {
    ByteBuffer tempButeBuf = Queue.getInstance().deQueue();
    // TODO: do something useful with the buffer
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

Comment: I have added the enqueue part.

Comment: "while( Queue.getInstance().getQueueCount() <= 0);" looks suspicious. Are you using that construct to "wait" for something to be pushed onto the queue? Or is it a typo? If indeed it's not, that must mean you have another thread that occasionally pushes objects onto the queue, or your program would hang forever. And that, in turn, suggests that what you have is a concurrency problem.

Comment: What you have guessed is correct indeed. There are two threads. One reads from the bluetooth stream puts it into the queue. The other one waits until there is a data available in queue. Once there is data, I carry out the necessary process to be done with the dequeued data. And I don't think its a concurrency problem either. As the document states, I should not get that exception. Plus there is data there in queue. :(

Comment: Ok. You should consider using a blocking queue instead of LinkedList. Have a look at this, for instance: [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), using the `take` method instead of `poll`. I don't doubt there's data in the queue, but clearly at the time of polling there isn't a _first element_ because poll (indirectly) does throw that exception if there is no first element.

Comment: I edited my comment adding suggested changes to the code. Also, if you haven't already, make sure that your singleton is thread safe!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try your suggestion and get back.

Comment: your suggested changes worked :) So its a concurrency issue after all. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I just noticed this. When I read the data from the queue, at random intervals it reads the same data. Plus the frequency of the same data read also varies. Is this because of offer() ? Shouldn't I use put()? And I am sure of the data I read from Bluetooth(which I enqueue), they are not the same.

Comment: The only difference between offer and put is that offer always returns immediately (returning true or false depending on whether the element was actually enqueued), while put waits until the queue isn't full before enqueueing and returning. So if you don't want your producer thread to hang if it fills the queue quicker than the consumer thread can read from it, you shouldn't use put.

Comment: What does the producer thread do with the ByteBuffer after enqueueing it?

Comment: Ok so in that case, I guess its not necessary then. The producer thread does nothing else other than enqueue work. But I am just wondering why the data is like that. I ll give you an example. Say the enqueue data is 4,8,12,16,(I am sure of this data)...and so on...on dequeue I get 4,12,12,16,...and this pattern occurs at random intervals.

Comment: The reason I asked is that if what you're really doing is enqueuing a reference to a ByteBuffer, as opposed to a copy of it, you will experience strange behaviour if you reuse the buffer in any way after enqueueing it.

Answer (score 0):

> peek:
>
> Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns
>   null if this queue is empty. Returns: the head of this queue, or null
>   if this queue is empty
>
> poll:
>
> Retrieves, and removes, the head of this queue, or returns
>   null if this queue is empty. Returns: the head of this queue, or null
>   if this queue is empty

So you can use the peek method. And also the problem in your question is that the queue is empty so be sure that you queue the data correctly

Comment: My queue count...I log them as I add to the queue                                                          03-04 14:58:50.225: D/BLUETOOTH_READ(7937): Data Added in Q!
03-04 14:58:50.225: D/BLUETOOTH_READ(7937): Queue Count: 102290

Comment: And i want to clear the queue after i dequeue, thats why i use poll()

Comment: Is your class name Queue? Why don't you just extend the java.util.Queue and override the methods you want?

Comment: Yes, my class name is Queue. And what's the purpose of extending and overriding here? I just need the basic queue implementations, so I guess it's not required?

Comment: So you can just use the java queue and that will be much easier . Why creating a class that does nothing more the java queue?

Comment: And it works as intended for a while. Once it throws that exception, it keeps throwing it. And I need to know why it throws such an exception when its not supposed to?

Comment: So that I can call them from other classes :) This is a kind of singleton class. I have a single object. I enqueue and dequeue in different class files.

Comment: But the poll does not remove the head as the java documentation states, is that what you want?

Comment: From the Android Documentation.                                                         
public abstract E poll ()
Added in API level 1

Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.
Returns

    the head of this queue, or null if this queue is empty

Comment: Can you instead of getQueueCount use if(!queue.isEmpty())

Comment: I don't think the "getQueueCount" has any issue. I ll try your suggestion and get back.

Comment: Emil suggestion worked :) Thank you for your help too :)